# How to call Javascript On Custom Action Button in Sharepoint Hosted App?

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created Custom Action Button In document Library using

```
<CustomAction Id="7be13ea1-8621-487b-b579-15e3b9d63908.CreateZip19"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="101"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Invoke &apos;CreateZip19&apos; action">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <!-- 
  Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
  that you want to enable for the custom action.
  -->
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.CreateZip19Button"
              Alt="Request CreateZip19"
              Sequence="100"
              Command="Invoke_CreateZip19ButtonRequest"
              LabelText="CreateZip19"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
              Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_CreateZip19ButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension >
```

Now In this code Command Action is compulsory . So it is redirect on other page when I click Button. I want to call only javascript function instead of redirecting page.
When One select Document Library files and Click On Button I need List of all selected File. I want to use only JSOM.
Please provide me some approach  for doing this.

Comment: trying to achieve the same but without luck... when I put javascript inside CommandAction the package gets undeployable with validation failed

Answer (score 1):

```
AddUserActions = function () {
            var userActionsDeferred = $.Deferred();
            var customActions = hostWeb.get_userCustomActions();
            hostContext.load(customActions);
                var siteAction = customActions.add();
                siteAction.set_title("My status bar");
                siteAction.set_description("custom description");
                siteAction.set_location("ScriptLink");
                siteAction.set_scriptSrc("~siteCollection/MyLibrary/Scripts/MyScript.js");
                siteAction.update();
                hostContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                $('#txtStatus').text('Success');
                userActionsDeferred.resolve();
            }, function (message) {
                userActionsDeferred.reject(message);
            });
            return userActionsDeferred.promise();
        }
```

Comment: Where do I need to add this code? Please provide some context to the code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can call JavaScript in `<CommandUIHandlers>` like:

```
 <CommandUIHandlers>

    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_CreateZip19ButtonRequest" CommandAction="javascript: var dialogOptions = function() {
                              alert('Custom Action Called');
                              };
                              SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', dialogOptions);
                              " /> 

 </CommandUIHandlers>
```

Comment: undeployable in provider-hosted add-in... because of the javascript... when I remove the javascript deploy works fine